# error in ldap_pvt_thread.h while giving 'make depend' to add dependencies

Tags: linux

I am configuring openldap-2.3.6 in my RHEL6 server, after running ./configure command successfully, I am getting the follwing error while adding dependencies using the command 'make depend'.
The error is:

## ../../include/ldap_pvt_thread.h:69:7: error: missing binary operator before token "("

I have checked line no.69 in ldap_pvt_thread.h, it goes like this:

```
 61 #define LDAP_PVT_THREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE 0
 62 #define LDAP_PVT_THREAD_CREATE_DETACHED 1
 63
 64 #define LDAP_PVT_THREAD_SET_STACK_SIZE
 65 #ifndef LDAP_PVT_THREAD_STACK_SIZE
 66         /* LARGE stack. Will be twice as large on 64 bit machine. */
 67 #define LDAP_PVT_THREAD_STACK_SIZE      ( 1 * 1024 * 1024 * sizeof(void *) )
 68 /* May be explicitly defined to zero to disable it */
 69 #elif LDAP_PVT_THREAD_STACK_SIZE == 0
 70 #undef LDAP_PVT_THREAD_SET_STACK_SIZE
 71 #endif
```

I have even tried by changing line no.69 to:
if defined( LDAP_PVT_THREAD_STACK_SIZE ) && LDAP_PVT_THREAD_STACK_SIZE == 0
but it dint workd...
it is driving me nuts ...what change do I need to make, please help....!

Answer (score 0):

Either you are using a fairly old branch of the code or somehow this [bug](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=505421) has got back into the code.

I can compile a recent branch without error, on an older branch (circa 2007) I get the problem.

The patch (indicated in the above link) works for me, I then have to configure with

CPPFLAGS=-D_GNU_SOURCE ./configure

to get round this subsequent error

getpeereid.c:64:15: error: storage size of peercred isn't known